# How to retry tasks on bad status code in httpclient response?

Tags: c#

My current idea was to get the number representations of the status codes and decide what to do based on those. However I'm hitting a roadblock of sorts.

When I'm checking browser requests in chrome there is this part to every response:

```
Request URL: SiteURL
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK //note this part
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8888
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

When I do something like this:

```
var response = Task.Run(() => this.HttpClient.GetAsync($"some_link"));
string pageHtml = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
string statusCode = response.Result.StatusCode.ToString();
```

I get just "OK" for a status code instead of "200 OK" when everything is fine.

**Is there a way to get the number representation of a status code?** I'm not sure how to work with the text versions at all since I've no idea what most of those would say, and also I'm not at all sure if there are OK status codes that would work. **Is it possible to get a status code of something different than "OK" and still get the requested page?** If the answer is "No" I guess that would solve my problems right than and there.

The ultimate idea is when I get a bad status code like 504, 502 (or possibly something different than a good status code) the program just retries the response every 5 minutes until the situation is fixed and continues working after that.

Comment: *"Is there a way to get the number representation of a status code?"* Afaik StatusCode is an enum, have you tried simply casting it to `int`?

Comment: *"Is it possible to get a status code of something different than "OK" and still get the requested page?"* Yes, depends on the server, unfortunately even the opposite can happen. You could get 200 OK but the site shows a 404.

Comment: I hadn't tried casting it to int. It worked great and gave me the code. However based on what you said in the second post I'm worried that the overall strategy I'm trying wouldn't work as flawlessly as I had thought. But as far as I can figure I wont be able to test this until such an error occurs again and see what code I'm getting than.

Comment: In *most* cases, the status code should represent the **actual** status of the response but as I said it's completely up to the server. Some servers don't give you error codes on purpose to (not very effectively) protect themselves from web-crawlers, scrapers and other automated tools.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll give it a try like this than and see if I hit a problem.